# How to show that $V_{\alpha +1}=V_{\alpha}\cup\mathscr{P}(V_{\alpha})$ for $\alpha <3$ when Atoms are Allowed (Enderton's Set Theory)?

Tags: set-theory

This question comes from Enderton's *Elements of Set Theory*, page nine.

$A$ is the set of atoms. For $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$, Enderton has defined $V_0:=A$ and $V_{\alpha +1}:=V_{\alpha}\cup\mathscr{P}(V_{\alpha})$.

**Exercise**:We have stated that $V_{\alpha +1}=A\cup\mathscr{P}(V_{\alpha})$. Prove this for at least $\alpha <3$.

I have computed this directly in the case that the set of atoms is empty, i.e., $A=\varnothing$.

I gather from the answer of user "Nagase" [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877532/prove-this-result-about-construction-of-sets) that transfinite induction is the best approach here, but Enderton won't teach that until Chapter Seven. Therefore I have to compute each level directly. I don't know how to do this for a general set of atoms $A$.

Comment: I suspect you're overthinking things. For example, you know $V_0$ by definition (it's $A$). Similarly, we have $$V_1=V_0\cup\mathscr{P}(V_0)=A\cup\mathscr{P}(A)=A\cup\mathscr{P}(V_0),$$ with the first equality being the definition of $V_{\alpha+1}$ and the second and third equalities each coming from the definition of $V_0$.  Do you see how to continue? (Note that there's no need to "dig into" the details of $A$ itself here.)

Comment: $V_2=V_1\cup\mathscr{P}(V_1)=A\cup\mathscr{P}(V_0)\cup\mathscr{P}(V_1)$. But how to show that $\mathscr{P}(V_0)\subset\mathscr{P}(V_1)$? Edit: I think I see. If something is an element of LHS, it is a set of atoms. But RHS contains all sets of atoms since we formed it by taking the power set of a set which has $A$ as a subset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this answer adopts the usual convention that "P or Q" means "P is true or Q is true or both P and Q are true".

- $V_1:=V_0\cup\mathscr{P}(V_0)=A\cup\mathscr{P}(V_0)$. This proves the claim for $\alpha = 0$. Note that each element of $V_1$ is an atom or a (possibly empty) set of atoms, but not both.
- $V_2:=V_1\cup\mathscr{P}(V_1)=A\cup\mathscr{P}(V_0)\cup\mathscr{P}(V_1)$. Every element of $\mathscr{P}(V_0)$ is a (possibly empty) set of atoms. Every element of $\mathscr{P}(V_1)$ is a (possibly empty) set containing atoms or sets of atoms, or both. Therefore $\mathscr{P}(V_0)\subset\mathscr{P}(V_1)$ and $V_2=V_0\cup\mathscr{P}(V_1)=A\cup\mathscr{P}(V_1)$
- $V_3:=V_2\cup\mathscr{P}(V_2)=A\cup\mathscr{P}(V_1)\cup\mathscr{P}(V_2)$. Every element of $\mathscr{P}(V_2)$ is a (possibly empty) set containing atoms or sets of atoms or sets of sets of atoms. Therefore $\mathscr{P}(V_1)\subset\mathscr{P}(V_2)$ and $V_3=A\cup\mathscr{P}(V_2)$. This proves the result for $\alpha = 2$.